# Line2D.Double from Java awt is not working as expected

Tags: java, awt

Nothing executes beyond the line "linePath.intersectsLine(barrier)"

Why is that the case?

```
var linePath = new Line2D.Double(dronelnglat.longitude, dronelnglat.latitude, nextPos.longitude(),
                nextPos.latitude());

//        checks if the move intersects with one of the edges of each of the no-fly zone polygons
        for (int i = 0; i < noFlyZones.size(); i++) {
            var nfzPoly = noFlyZones.get(i);
            var nfzPoints = nfzPoly.coordinates().get(0);
            for (int j = 0; j < nfzPoints.size() - 1; j++) {
                Line2D barrier = new Line2D.Double(nfzPoints.get(j).longitude(),
                        nfzPoints.get(j).latitude(),
                        nfzPoints.get(j + 1).longitude(),
                        nfzPoints.get(j + 1).latitude());
                if (linePath.intersectsLine(barrier)) {
                    System.out.println("Surprise me!");
                    crossNoFlyZone = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

I plotted the points and the lines clearly intersect. The parameters are passed in the correct way around as well.

To reproduce the problem, do the following steps:
The line path coordinates can be found here:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/2ht83msir2ehp7e/flightpath-2023-01-01.json/file

The coordinates of the no-fly zone can be found here:
https://ilp-rest.azurewebsites.net/noflyzones

If you drag and drop these files on https://geojson.io/ you should be able to visualize it.

Comment: Seems to work for me.  Edit your question and show your input data, so we can reproduce your problem for ourselves.

Comment: Sure :) I have updated the post. Thank you for your time to look into the problem.

Comment: Thank you, but I’m afraid we need example data to be embedded in your question.  The problem with external links is that they may go away eventually, which would make your question useless to future readers.  When you have time, please create a smaller data set which will illustrate the problem and embed it directly in your question.